# Javascript - How to remove all elements of an array within an array

Tags: javascript

Currently when I console.log(deckOfCards), it is returning
all 52 cards, each with a suit, value, and points assigned to them.

```
{ suit: '♦', value: 'A', points: 11 }
{ suit: '♦', value: 2, points: 2 }
{ suit: '♦', value: 3, points: 3 }
.....
```

Now, I want to remove one card that has the suit, value and points from my deckOfCards array and return that.

```
{ suit: '♦', value: 'A', points: 11 }
```

This is to simulate dealing one card from the deck.

I have tried accessing each index of the array and adding them to the card variable, but it gave me an undefined for index 2.

For loops only return one array of suits and not the others.

I have changed the deckOfCards into an object that has the suit, value, and points in it.

My card constant is where I want to pull one card from the deck.

```
const suits = ["♦", "♣", "♥", "♠"];
const values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];

for (const suit of suits) {
 for (const value of values) {

  let points = parseInt(value);
   if(value === "J" || value === "Q" || value === "K") points = 10;
   if(value === "A") points = 11;

  const deckOfCards = {suit, value, points};

  const card = deckOfCards

 }
}
```

*EDIT* *TRYING TO ADD NEW METHOD*

I'm trying to add two cards each to the player/dealer hands,
but when i log it:

```
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 } ]
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 },
  { suit: '♦', value: 10, points: 10 } ]
```

Why am I getting 3 objects returned instead of 2?

```
const dealRandomCard = () => {
 return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];
}

// console.log(dealRandomCard());

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for (let i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
 playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
 dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  console.log(playerHand);
// console.log(dealerHand);
}
```

Comment: What about the Joker?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. where is the removing part?

Comment: You are redefining your array inside the loop. It will never have more than one suit, value or points (it also will not be accessible anyway out of the scope of the loop since you're defining it inside it).

Comment: @DanielWilliams no Joker in this deck

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry, has been revised, hopefully more clear on what i'd like to achieve

Comment: @MarcoBonelli i've redefined it as an object with each variable. Not sure if that'll work. I'm just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: `parseInt("A")` will return NaN

Comment: @Anakin { suit: '♣', value: 'A', points: 11 }

Comment: @Anakin you're right, when i log parseInt("A"), it gives me NaN, but when i log the deckOfCards, it gives me above. Not sure what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single combined object to the result set. And an object for a  shorter way of getting the points.

```js
var suits = ["♦", "♣", "♥", "♠"],
    values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"],
    cards = [],
    suit,
    value,
    points = { A: 11, J: 10, Q: 10, K: 10 };

for (suit of suits) {
   for (value of values) {
       cards.push({ suit, value, points: points[value] || value });
    }
}

function getCard() {
    return cards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length), 1)[0];
}

console.log(getCard());
console.log(getCard());
console.log(getCard());
console.log(cards);
```

Comment: thanks. that's much clearer that what I have, but how would I grab one object from that array of objects, as if to simulate a dealer handing out one card from the deck?

Comment: first 14 element of `cards` are diamonds next 14 are clubs and so on...

Comment: What is going on at the end of the getCards function. , 1)[0]

Comment: splice is taking one element and returns an array of spliced elements. and while you need a single object and not an object wrapped in an array, it take the first or the only element.

Comment: @Anakin, `cards` is a sorted array, because it is build by the two `for` loops.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm trying to add two hands each to  a playerHand array and dealerHand array but when i console log it. it prints out 3 objects instead of 2.