# Javascript - how to add points from one array to another - so I can tally them up and compare the two

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the value of the 2 cards in each Hand array to points, so that I can tally them up and
compare the two.

Currently, it says my playerPoints is NaN, so my issue is
in the for-of loop or my playerHand.point.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
 dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
}
 // console.log(playerHand);
 // console.log(dealerHand);

let playerPoints = 0,
 dealerPoints = 0;

for (point of playerHand) {
 playerPoints += playerHand.point;
}
console.log(playerPoints);
```

*REVISED - WORKING CODE - Thanks to Nina*

```
for (let { points } of playerHand {
    playerPoints += points
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm fairly confident playerHand is nothing more than an array

Comment: That `for` syntax is invalid. it should be `for (card of playerHand) playerPoints += card.point` or something like that (it depends of what `card` is)

Comment: Lexically, it would be more clear if the property were named "points" instead of the singular form "point." Is there a mismatch between the naming somewhwre? Elsewhere you use the plural in your naming scheme.

Comment: btw, no need to change the question after an aswer to include the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the objects of a [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736888/1447675) of OP of the same kind, it should be `points` in stead of `point`.

Beside this, you need to take the `points` property by using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
for (let { points } of playerHand) {
    playerPoints += points;
}
```

Comment: thank you. So the point of putting points into an object is so that it can unpack the values from the array and be able to add them to the playerPoints?

Comment: it *unpacks* or better takes a **destructuring assignment** from an object. `of playerHand` returns items of the array which are objects.